# Trying to set symfony locale to something else than fr and en_US

Tags: php, symfony, translation

I am trying to make a multi-language application on Symfony2 and I was wondering why when I use this `$this->get('session')->setLocale('fr');` it works (finds the file `/src/ggirtsou/MyBundle/Resources/Translations/messages.fr.xliff`) but when I set it to something like: el_GR it won't work.

I tried many variations (el, GR, EL, GR_el) but none of them worked. Kept getting the non-translated string.

I know I am missing something here and can't figure this out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have *messages.gr.xliff* file in Resources/Translations folder. After adding languages always clear the cache.